# How can I use a Webdriver Testcontainer in Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: webdriver, bitbucket-pipelines, testcontainers

When trying to use a Webdriver Testcontainer in Bitbucket Pipelines, I get the following error messages:

```
[main] WARN  [selenium/standalone-chrome:4.1.1] - Unable to mount a file from test host into a running container. This may be a misconfiguration or limitation of your Docker environment. Some features might not work.
[main] ERROR  [selenium/standalone-chrome:4.1.1] - Could not start container
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerException: Status 403: {"message":"authorization denied by plugin pipelines: -v only supports $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR and its subdirectories"}
```

My testcontainers version is 1.17.6

Here is the code I'm using while trying to troubleshoot:

```java
package com.byzpass.demo;

import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer;

public class SeleniumTest {
    public ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--no-sandbox").addArguments("--headless").addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    @Rule
    public BrowserWebDriverContainer<?> driverContainer = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>().withCapabilities(chromeOptions);

    @Test
    public void openWikipedia() {
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(driverContainer.getSeleniumAddress(), chromeOptions);
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.wikipedia.org/");
        String subtitleText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#www-wikipedia-org h1 strong")).getText();
        assert subtitleText.equals("The Free Encyclopedia");
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("Finished opening wikipedia.       ✨");
    }
}
```

Here is my bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        image: amazoncorretto:11
        services:
          - docker
        script:
          - export TESTCONTAINERS_RYUK_DISABLED=true
          - cd selenium-test ; bash ./mvnw --no-transfer-progress test

definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      memory: 2048
```

By setting a breakpoint in my test method and using `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}'` I was able to discover that the container for the selenium/standalone-chrome:4.1.1 image has `[{bind  /dev/shm /dev/shm  rw true rprivate}]`

I thought that using the --disable-dev-shm-usage argument in my chrome options would prevent that, but it didn't. I don't know whether that's what's causing my issue in Bitbucket Pipelines though.

Comment: Most probably that `/dev/shm` mount is the root cause, yes. The error message clearly points to a mount outside `$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR` and this is a known phenomena https://stackoverflow.com/a/72501955/11715259 . I am clueless on how to disable that mount for your web driver container. I fear the `--disable-dev-shm-usage` is being passed to the chrome command but the container would mount `/dev/shm` nonetheless. You should get rid of that mount or somehow override it.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it worked after setting shm size to zero. Here's the code that worked:

```java
package com.byzpass.demo;

import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testcontainers.containers.BrowserWebDriverContainer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SeleniumTest {
    @Test
    public void openWikipedia() {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--no-sandbox").addArguments("--headless").addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        BrowserWebDriverContainer driverContainer = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>().withRecordingMode(BrowserWebDriverContainer.VncRecordingMode.SKIP, null);

        driverContainer.setShmSize(0L);

        driverContainer.start();

        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(driverContainer.getSeleniumAddress(), chromeOptions);
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.wikipedia.org/");
        String subtitleText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#www-wikipedia-org h1 strong")).getText();
        assert subtitleText.equals("The Free Encyclopedia");
        driver.quit();

        driverContainer.stop();

        System.out.println("Finished opening wikipedia.       ✨");
    }
}
```